# Cannot copy from my home folder to a pen drive: "Read-only file system" error

Tags: gnome-terminal, usb-drive, copy

My pen drive is already mounted. First, I tried to access my pen drive from the terminal:

```
nazmul@nazmul-Lenovo-G50-80:~$ cd /media/nazmul/NAZMUL/
nazmul@nazmul-Lenovo-G50-80:/media/nazmul/NAZMUL$ ls Assignments      
document.pdf                      k-anonymity.pdf     
nazmul@nazmul-Lenovo-G50-80:/media/nazmul/NAZMUL$
```

Then, I tried to copy some of my folders to my pen drive. But I could not:

```
nazmul@nazmul-Lenovo-G50-80:~$ cp -r /home/nazmul/2nd_sem/hpca/* /media/nazmul/NAZMUL/

cp: cannot create regular file '/media/nazmul/NAZMUL/ct1-18.pdf':
Read-only file system

cp: cannot create regular file '/media/nazmul/NAZMUL/CT1-Sample
Question Paper Solution2.pdf': Read-only file system
```

Why I am getting this error?

Comment: Do your pen-drive have a "write protect" switch somewhere ? Or wasn't it properly unmounted last time it was used ?

Comment: Is it mounted read-only? `mount | grep /media/nazmul`. Is it an NTFS-formatted USB key last used on Windows? Will `sudo mount -o remount,rw ...` help?

Comment: @SorenA IT does not have any switch. But second case can be.

Comment: @waltinator /dev/sdb1 on /media/nazmul/NAZMUL type vfat (ro,nosuid,nodev,relatime,uid=1000,gid=1000,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,showexec,utf8,flush,errors=remount-ro,uhelper=udisks2) ---this is output of our first command

Comment: It's probably defective. Becoming "read only" is the first symptom. If the contents are important backup NOW!

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia what is defective? pen-drive? There is anyway to solve it ?

Comment: Yes, the drive, of course. No, there's no fix.